# Wrong pdflastxpos value with XeLaTeX+bidi

Tags: xetex, bidi

*The answer from Vala helped me to rephrase my question. See the original one below.*

Using `pdfsavepos` to get absolute position of texts on the page, I faced the following problems when using XeLaTeX in right-to-left mode. The sample code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=20000000sp,paperheight=10000000sp,
            hmargin=2000000sp,vmargin=1000000sp]{geometry}
\usepackage[enable,step=1000000sp,tr]{bidipagegrid}
\usepackage{bidi}
\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\def\where#1{\pdfsavepos\write-1{XPOS(#1)=\the\pdflastxpos}%
  \if@RTL\immediate\write-1{XPOS(#1) is RTL}\fi\ignorespaces}
\makeatother

\noindent \where{A1}AA\where{A2}

\begin{itemize}
  \item[\where{X1}X\where{X2}] 
    \hspace*{0pt}\where{D1}DtoD\where{D2}{} xxx \LR{x\where{E1}EtoE\where{E2}x}
\end{itemize}

\setRL

\noindent \where{B1}BB\where{B2}{} \LR{x\where{C1}CtoC\where{C2}x}

\begin{itemize}
  \item[\where{Y1}Y\where{Y2}] 
    \hspace*{0pt}\where{G1}GtoG\where{G2}{} xxx \LR{x\where{H1}HtoH\where{H2}x}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

outputs the following values in the log file:

```
XPOS(B1) is RTL  XPOS(B2) is RTL
XPOS(Y1) is RTL  XPOS(Y2) is RTL
XPOS(G1) is RTL  XPOS(G2) is RTL
XPOS(A1)=2,000,000 XPOS(A2)=2,983,042
XPOS(X1)=2,819,201 XPOS(X2)=3,310,722
XPOS(D1)=3,638,402 XPOS(D2)=5,222,192
XPOS(E1)=7,042,642 XPOS(E2)=8,517,206
XPOS(B1)=2,000,000 XPOS(B2)=2,928,430
XPOS(C1)=3,492,769 XPOS(C2)=5,021,945
XPOS(Y1)=1,180,799 XPOS(Y2)=1,672,320
XPOS(G1)=2,000,000 XPOS(G2)=3,611,096
XPOS(H1)=5,431,546 XPOS(H2)=6,997,132
```

and produces the following page (grid step is 1,000,000sp):
[image: Sample page output]

I would like to know the marked positions on the page. This seems easy for A, X, D, E (all in LTR mode) and even B (B is RTL so counting from the right), but I have questions for C (LTR text but measured from the right, and C1 and C2 are switched), G (seem to be shifted) and H (both shifted and switched).
Could anybody help me to get absolute positions from `pdflastposx` output?

**Original question, for reference.**

The following code gives wrong X location values for the right-to-left writing part (B).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bidi}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\def\where#1{\pdfsavepos\write-1{XPOS(#1)=\the\pdflastxpos}%
  \if@RTL\immediate\write-1{XPOS(#1) is RTL}\fi\ignorespaces}
\makeatother

\where{A0} First \where{A1} line here in RTL mode...

\setRL

\where{B0} Second \where{B1} one \LR{h\where{B2}er\where{B3}e}

\end{document}
```

It seems that some of these X values increase from right to left: the log file gets

```
XPOS(B0) is RTL
XPOS(B1) is RTL
XPOS(A0)=8799518
XPOS(A1)=11380911
XPOS(B0)=8799518
XPOS(B1)=12003504
XPOS(B2)=13569089
XPOS(B3)=14117043
```

But I think we should have A0 < A1 < B2 < B3 < B1 < B0 (if looking at the PDF). Could anybody give me a clue to get the right values?

Note that with an old version of texlive (2012-06-11 from debian squeeze), I get

```
XPOS(B0) is RTL
XPOS(B1) is RTL
XPOS(A0)=8799518
XPOS(A1)=11380911
XPOS(B0)=8799518
XPOS(B2)=26164732
XPOS(B3)=26712686
XPOS(B1)=26712686
```

with the same resulting PDF.

Answer (score 1):

> The following code gives wrong X location values for the right-to-left
>   writing part (B).

No, it is not wrong.

> It seems that some of these X values increase from right to left.

That is what it should be.

> But I think we should have A0 < A1 < B2 < B3 < B1 < B0 (if looking at
>   the PDF).

No, you are wrong. When you are in LTR mode, the x coordinate of the reference point is on the left hand side of the pdf (where the line starts) and when you are in RTL mode, the x coordinate of the reference point is on the right hand side of the pdf (where the line starts) and that is completely ok and logical.

Indeed, you should have A0=B0, A1~=B1 and A0 < A1 < B2 < B3 and that is what you have.

> Could anybody give me a clue to get the right values?

It gives you already the right values. Anyways, `bidi` package has nothing to do with this. This all happens at the engine level.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  Would you care to comment on the old values from texlive 2012 that the poster mentions?

Comment: @AndrewSwann: I have no idea. Sorry. As I said it all happens at the engine level so perhaps the behavior of `xetex` engine was modified somehow. The `bidi` package does not even touch `\pdfsavepos` and `\pdflastxpos` primitives.

Comment: And what about B2 and B3? We do have B2<B3 as a LTR text, but the values refer to distance from the right side of the page. If we consider B2 and B3 as distance from the left side of the page, the values are wrong, but if we consider B2 and B3 as distances from the right side of the page, the values are swapped.

Comment: @JojoBoulix: I see that but even then that is engine bug since `bidi` has nothing to do with this. This arises in a number of other scenarios, for example try two consecutive `\label` one immediate after the other and then look at the `.aux` file, you will see that the order is reversed. This is `TeX--XeT` bug.

Comment: I believe, Khaled Hosny has fixed it in the engine. Can you build `xetex` and `xdvipdfmx` from source and try to see if it is fixed or not?

Comment: @Vafa: I'm using texlive-binaries 2014.20140926.35254-2 from debian: do you think the fix is more recent? I'm afraid it will be hard for me to try from source.

Comment: @JojoBoulix: I think it is but there is no harm in building from source. If you have trouble building `xetex` and `xdvipdfmx` from source, please email Khaled Hosny. I think he is on debian too and perhaps can send you the binary files.

Comment: @Vafa: I asked Khaled Hosny and, while I'm setting up a devel version of xetex on my computer, he kindly sent me the output obtained with his version: unfortunately the XPOS values are exactly the same.